# How to split a large dataframe into multiple dataframe based on the first 3 characters of the column names?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a huge dataframe (2077 columns) that I would like to break down into multiple dataframes (78 exactly). Each column name starts with a 3 letter acronym (coc, cou, wam etc.). How would I split up the master dataframe into multiple smaller data frames based on the first 3 letters of the column names?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `groupby` with a lambda and iterate over the group object to separate them out into a list of DataFrames:

```
df_list = [g for _, g in df.groupby(by=lambda x: x[:3], axis=1)]
```

If you want a mapping of {prefix : dataFrame} instead, you can create a dictionary:

```
df_dict = {k: g for k, g in df.groupby(by=lambda x: x[:3], axis=1)}
```

Comment: These answers are perfect! Thanks for your speedy reply. :D

Comment: @a.parris It's in my name after all, yw

Comment: I do have one more question actually. For the dataframe, I would like to keep the first column (the id number). Would it be possible to state in that line that I would like to keep the 'id' column?

Comment: @a.parris First do `df = df.set_index('id')` and then run this code.